# Add TextBox in GridView at specific column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this GridView:

```
<fieldset class="loadedform">
                <legend>OD</legend>
                <asp:GridView ID="Grv_OD" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LbPr_Id"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="Grv_OD_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="Grv_OD_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="Chk_Items" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LbPr_Id" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LbPr_Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LbPr_ParentId" Visible="false" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </fieldset>
```

I want to add a TextBox column in the GridView at a specific column. When I bound GridView to this:

```
if flag bit equal to 1
```

then this field is a comment and I have to place a TextBox column in this GridView row.
I don't have any idea for this problem?
I then follow picture hoping it could explain it correctly:
I want to display the TextBox column in GridView at specific column when I checked corresponding check box.

Comment: Which picture did you try and follow?

Answer (score 0):

use template field to add textbox to GridView.

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

if you want to check the value and manipulate your Gridview based on the value. that you can do this in `RowDataBound` event of your gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can use Template Field to do the same.

Template Field actually allow you to add TextBox as a separate column within the GridView.

Below is the code for the same :-

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

You can add one Checkbox control outside the GridView & on the click event of that Checkbox, you need to write logic in order to show/ hide the template column of the GridView that contains textbox.

Hope it helps you.